# How to clone tr in table using jquery

Tags: jquery

Have a lot of tables on the page. I want to add new row with existing data after some one `tr`. So I have one of the table:

```
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>...</th>
                <td>...</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p id="add-tr">[add]</p>
```

And when I click to `[add]`, I want to add a new `tr` with existing `th` and `td` elements.
I found last table with:

```
$('#add-tr').on('click',function(){
    $(this).prev('table')...;
    });
```

(checked with hide() func) What to do next? Tried:

```
$(this).prev('table').closest('tr').clone();
```

But no effect!

My first question at stackoverflow! So not too harsh, and thanks!

Comment: `<th>` must relate to `<thead>` or `<tfoot>` parts of the table and shouldn't be mixed with regular `<td>` elements.

Comment: You've got to do something with the cloned row (append it the table), rather than just calling `clone()` on it.

Comment: @VisioN as I understand, this is a perfectly acceptable way to use `<th>` -- they don't NEED to be inside a `<thead>`, that's just semantic markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were really close, just need to select the tr inside using .find() not .closest(), then choose where to .appendTo():

```
$('#add-tr').on('click',function(){
    $(this).prev('table').find('tr').first().clone().appendTo('table');
});​
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use `find` or `children` method and append the row, `closest` method selects the closest parent of the element.

```
var $table = $(this).prev('table');
$table.find('tr:first').clone().appendTo($table);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have it cloned right but now you need to actually append it:

```
var myRow = $(this).prev('table').closest('tr').clone();

$(this).prev('table').closest('tr').append(myRow);
```

or similar