# how to add new input row and insert into database and error appearing Uninitialized string offset: 0 in

Tags: javascript, php, function, input, sql-insert

I am trying to insert new input row in database. but error showing (Uninitialized string offset: 0 in)

Single row i can insert fine but 2 or more row can not insert because error appearing.

I searched alot but did not found perfect solution. Please see my code and give me suggestion. Thanks

My Html Code Below:-

```
<div id="addhere">
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control item_id" value="" readonly="" name="item_id[]"></td>
    <td><textarea class="form-control item_name" name="item_name[]" rows="3"></textarea> </td> 
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control item_qty" value="" name="item_qty[]"></td> 
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control item_price" name="item_price[]" value="" style="width: 89px;"></td> 
    <td> <select class="form-control item_taxed" name="item_taxed[]">
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option> <option value="No" selected="">No</option></select></td>
    <td> <select class="form-control item_status" name="item_status[]" style="width: 89px;">
    <option value="Paid">Paid</option> <option value="Not Paid" selected="">No Paid</option></select></td>

    <td><input type="text" name="datepicker[]" class="date1" placeholder="Enter date" class="mycalendar" class="form-control item_price" value="" style="width: 84px;"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="departing[]" class="date2" placeholder="Enter date" class="mycalendar" class="form-control" style="width: 84px;"></td>

    </tr>
</div>
```

For New form Row Javascript Function Below:-

```
$('#blank-add').on('click', function(){
    $("#invoice_items").find('tbody')
        .append(
        '<tr> <td><input type="text" class="form-control item_id" value="" readonly="" name="item_id"></td> <td><textarea class="form-control item_name" name="item_name" rows="3"></textarea></td> <td><input type="text" class="form-control qty" value="" name="item_qty"></td> <td><input type="text" class="form-control item_price" name="item_price" value=""></td><td> <select class="form-control item_taxed" name="item_taxed"> <option value="Yes">Yes</option> <option value="No" selected>No</option></select></td><td> <select class="form-control item_status" name="item_status" style="width: 89px;"><option value="Paid">Paid</option> <option value="Not Paid" selected="">No Paid</option></select></td><td><input type="text" name="datepicker" class="date1" placeholder="Enter date" class="mycalendar" class="form-control item_price" value="" style="width: 84px;"></td><td><input type="text" name="departing" class="date2" placeholder="Enter date" class="mycalendar" class="form-control" style="width: 84px;"></td></tr>'
    );
    });
```

and my php code below:-

```
<?php
// inserting invoice data into database name "billing"

if(isset($_POST['_dec_point'])){
    for ( $row = 0; $row < count( $_POST['item_id'] ); ++$row ) {
        $item_id = $_POST['item_id'][$row]; 
        $item_name = $_POST['item_name'][$row];
        $item_qty = $_POST['item_qty'][$row];
        $item_price = $_POST['item_price'][$row];
        $item_taxed = $_POST['item_taxed'][$row];
        $item_status = $_POST['item_status'][$row];
        $invoice_date = date('Y-m-d',  strtotime($_POST['datepicker']))[$row];
        $due_date = date('Y-m-d',  strtotime($_POST['departing']))[$row];
        $item_notes = $_POST['item_notes'][$row];
        $client_name = $_POST['client_name'][$row];
        $client_email = $_POST['client_email'][$row];
        $client_phone = $_POST['client_phone'][$row];
        $client_company = $_POST['client_company'][$row];
        $client_address = $_POST['client_address'][$row];
        $client_city = $_POST['client_city'][$row];
        $client_state = $_POST['client_state'][$row];
        $client_pin = $_POST['client_pin'][$row];
        $client_country = $_POST['client_country'][$row];

        $query = "insert into billing 
                       (item_id,item_name,item_qty,item_price,
                        item_taxed,item_status,invoice_date,due_date,
                        item_notes,client_name,client_email,
                        client_phone,client_company,
                        client_address,client_city, 
                        client_state, client_pin,
                        client_country)                         
                 values ('$item_id','$item_name','$item_qty',
                         '$item_price','$item_taxed','$item_status',
                         '$invoice_date','$due_date','$item_notes',
                         '$client_name','$client_email',
                         '$client_phone','$client_company',
                         '$client_address','$client_city',
                         '$client_state','$client_pin',
                         '$client_country')";
        }

        $run_insert = mysqli_query($con,$query);

        if($run_insert){
            $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
            echo "<script>alert('Submission Successful!')</script>";
            echo "<script>window.open('invoices_view.php?view=$last_id','_self')</script>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you adopt a good indentation scheme simple issues like this will become almost obvious.

You have terminated you `for` loop before executing the query, therefore you will only ever update the last row

You are also using `++$row` which increments `$row` before using it, amybe this shoudl be `$row++` increment after.

```
<?php
// inserting invoice data into database name "billing"

if(isset($_POST['_dec_point'])){
   /*
      Not sure why you are using ++$row rather than $row++
      That also may explain why you are loosing the first
      update out of 2.
   */

    for ( $row = 0; $row < count( $_POST['item_id'] ); ++$row ) {
        $item_id = $_POST['item_id'][$row]; 
        $item_name = $_POST['item_name'][$row];
        $item_qty = $_POST['item_qty'][$row];
        $item_price = $_POST['item_price'][$row];
        $item_taxed = $_POST['item_taxed'][$row];
        $item_status = $_POST['item_status'][$row];
        $invoice_date = date('Y-m-d',  strtotime($_POST['datepicker']))[$row];
        $due_date = date('Y-m-d',  strtotime($_POST['departing']))[$row];
        $item_notes = $_POST['item_notes'][$row];
        $client_name = $_POST['client_name'][$row];
        $client_email = $_POST['client_email'][$row];
        $client_phone = $_POST['client_phone'][$row];
        $client_company = $_POST['client_company'][$row];
        $client_address = $_POST['client_address'][$row];
        $client_city = $_POST['client_city'][$row];
        $client_state = $_POST['client_state'][$row];
        $client_pin = $_POST['client_pin'][$row];
        $client_country = $_POST['client_country'][$row];

        $query = "insert into billing 
                   (item_id,item_name,item_qty,item_price,
                    item_taxed,item_status,invoice_date,due_date,
                    item_notes,client_name,client_email,
                    client_phone,client_company,
                    client_address,client_city, 
                    client_state, client_pin,
                    client_country)                         
             values ('$item_id','$item_name','$item_qty',
                     '$item_price','$item_taxed','$item_status',
                     '$invoice_date','$due_date','$item_notes',
                     '$client_name','$client_email',
                     '$client_phone','$client_company',
                     '$client_address','$client_city',
                     '$client_state','$client_pin',
                     '$client_country')";

    // } // endfor <-- comment this and add the one below

        $run_insert = mysqli_query($con,$query);

    /*
       This code makes little sence here if you are 
       going to update more than one billing at a time
    */
        if($run_insert){
            $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
            echo "<script>alert('Submission Successful!')</script>";
            echo "<script>window.open('invoices_view.php?view=$last_id','_self')</script>";
        } // endif

    } // endfor  <-- move the endfor to here

}
?>
```

I also have to assume that this piece of code you showed us in repeated more than once on your actual page.

```
<div id="addhere">
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control item_id" value="" readonly="" name="item_id[]"></td>
    <td><textarea class="form-control item_name" name="item_name[]" rows="3"></textarea> </td> 
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control item_qty" value="" name="item_qty[]"></td> 
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control item_price" name="item_price[]" value="" style="width: 89px;"></td> 
    <td> <select class="form-control item_taxed" name="item_taxed[]">
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option> <option value="No" selected="">No</option></select></td>
    <td> <select class="form-control item_status" name="item_status[]" style="width: 89px;">
    <option value="Paid">Paid</option> <option value="Not Paid" selected="">No Paid</option></select></td>

    <td><input type="text" name="datepicker[]" class="date1" placeholder="Enter date" class="mycalendar" class="form-control item_price" value="" style="width: 84px;"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="departing[]" class="date2" placeholder="Enter date" class="mycalendar" class="form-control" style="width: 84px;"></td>

    </tr>
</div>
```

Also to your javascript method of creating a new row in your table. Can I suggest that you take a look at cloneing the last row, and then clearing all the input fields. That way you dont have to maintain a seperate piece of HTML defining the content of that row, which is eventually going to trip you, or someone else up when the row changes and you forget to amend that piece of JS. [Example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961445/how-to-clone-tr-in-table-using-jquery)

**In fact thats exactly what has happened!**

I just looked closer at that exact javascript code and there is another issue in there. You have named the input fields incorrectly

None of them have the array indicator `[]` after their names, so you only get 1 occurance of all those fields when you use the JS to add a new row to the table. So consider the clone method now!

Comment: changed the curly bracket " } " position as you mentioned. but still same error and only 1 value updating.

Comment: See the `++$row` comment I just saw that one

Comment: I think ++$row and $row++ shouldn't make a difference here. As that is going to execute only after the loop body has finished?

Comment: @codeHeart Must admit I was not 100% on that one, but at this stage I would try and remove anything out of the ordinary

Comment: See additional info in answer, about your javascript click code

Comment: Yup I think you have the complete solution, but that would be upto OP to decide ;)

Comment: ok i changed $row++  and also changed javascript code . now both of input values inserting in database after change $raw++. but problem is that Errore still appearing. but both of values updating now.

Javascript code below:-

<code>

 <!-- inserting add new row field in html -->
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#blank-add").click(function() {
        $('#invoice_items tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#invoice_items tbody>tr:last');
    return false;
    });
    });
</script> 

</code>

Comment: That error should contain a line number, can you indictae which line in this code the error is happening on please.

Comment: Problem Solved. From $item_notes to $client_country I Removed [$row].

and working fine Because From $item_notes to $client_country variables for another form . I was mixing by mistake lol.

also my earlier javascript code is working fine as well. So mainly i changed  $row++ and curly bracket place also changed input names as an array like this name="item_id[]". and everything working fine now.

Thanks alot

Comment: can you please tell me how can i display clone field data and parent field row data together. because i am creating invoice software and want to display both inserted field together in invoice page.please suggest me. Thanks